# How to submit post/put request to Django rest API via React front end?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django, this is hopefully an easy question for the advanced users.
I'm trying to submit a post/put request to a nested object in Django rest API using a React form (front end).

Below is how the nested object looks like, the table is called `person`. It's joins to the address table to get information such as street, suburb etc..

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "last_name": "Kidd",
    "first_name": "Jason",
    "address": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "street": "13 Sunrise Road",
            "suburb": "Greenhithe",
            "town": "Christchurch",
            "postcode": "2234",
            "address_type": "w"
        }
    ],
    "group": "Customer"
}
```

I used a package called `drf_writable_nested` to write to the nested object. This is the code for `person serializer`.

```
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class PersonSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    address = AddressSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'address', 'group')
```

Below is the front end code for handling the submit request, such pattern works fine if the object it submits to is flat (not nested).

```
class ClientForm extends React.Component {

    handleFormSubmit = (event, requestType, id) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const last_name = event.target.elements.last_name.value;
        const first_name = event.target.elements.first_name.value;

        console.log(last_name, first_name);
        switch ( requestType ) {
            case 'post':
                return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/person/', {
                    last_name: last_name,
                    first_name: first_name
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.err(error));
            case 'put':
                return axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/person/${id}/`, {
                    last_name: last_name,
                    first_name: first_name
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }
    }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleFormSubmit(
                    event,
                    this.props.requestType,
                    this.props.id)}>
              <Form.Item label="Last name" style={{width: "250px"}}>
                <Input name="last_name" placeholder="Enter surname here" />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item label="First name" style={{width: "250px", textAlign: 'center'}} >
                <Input name="first_name" placeholder="Enter first name here" />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </Form>
          </div>
        );
      }
}

export default ClientForm;
```

My question is how should I modify it to make it work with a nested object? If modification is not possible, what's the alternative way? Within the form, I wish to have fields like `last name`, `first name`, `street`, `suburb`, `town` to submit information to the API.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Did you try calling your Django API from POSTMAN with the nested request body?

Comment: @VaibhavSingh hey mate thanks for the response. No, zubhav's solution looks like an easier one. I will try that first, will explore POSTMAN if that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client-side, you need to structure the payload in such a way that the API is able to understand it.

You can collate the information within a form with whatever fields you like. But when you are submitting to the API, it must be in the correct format according to the API.

So within the React form, you might want to construct an object in state based on the filled-in form fields.

This might look like:

```
{
   first_name: "John",
   last_name: "Smith",
   address: {
      suburb: "",
      street: "",
      town: ""
   }
}
```

You'll need to check what format the Django API accepts the payload.

Comment: Thanks mate. It took me a while to get my head around this, but I eventually got there.